# can I read/write the routing table in C without using system() command?

Tags: c, linux, networking, routes

I have code written in C. I want to get using C code information that is stored in routing table. Is it possible?

Comment: How do you think `route` command does that if that is impossible?

Comment: https://olegkutkov.me/2019/08/29/modifying-linux-network-routes-using-netlink/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can open a netlink socket and send route update messages. There is [an article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356) about how to do this.

Comment: once i have sent getroute message, I don't know what structure is going to be there in the reply, any help?

Answer (score 12):

You can also run "strace route add ..." to see how the `route` command does it.

On my system, it uses `ioctl` with `SIOCADDRT`.  A little searching turns up some [sample code](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/how-to-add-a-gateway-address-using-ioctl-in-c-in-linux-512213/).

Oddly, the best documentation I have found is from [IBM's AS400 man pages](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/html/as400/v4r5/ic2962/info/apis/sioctl.htm#Header_25).

If you just want to read the routing table, you can open and read `/proc/net/route`.  (Again, `strace` shows that this is how the `route` command does it.)  The hex numbers are 32-bit IP addresses in machine-endian form.  Try `cat /proc/net/route`.

Comment: ioctl does not look to have an option to query the route. SIOCADDRT writes to the kernel table. I just need to read

Comment: The title of your question says "modify".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query the routing table only, try to read the file `/proc/net/route`. It works in my system.