# Structure definition not found for rt_msghdr

Tags: c, linux, networking, routes

I want to obtain some information about routing table using the UNIX networking api. To do this i'm using the routing socket and send a request to the kernel with rt_msghdr structure that as i read is defined in net/route.h. The version of the os is:

> Linux version 4.14.0-kali3-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc version 7.2.0
>   (Debian 7.2.0-18)) #1 SMP Debian 4.14.12-2kali1 (2018-01-08).

Unfortunatly in the route.h file in my system there isn't the definition for the rt_msghdr structure. How can i fix it?
Thanks you indeed  and sorry for my English

Comment: `Linux` != `Unix`. `rt_msghdr` is defined in `/usr/include/net/route.h` on my `FreeBSD`.

Comment: Ok thanks so do you know where is defined on linux?

Comment: It is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can I read/write the routing table in C without using system() command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358431/can-i-read-write-the-routing-table-in-c-without-using-system-command)

Comment: You might also try `grep -IR "rt_msghdr" /usr/include` to locate headers that use it.

Comment: Nothing as result jww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

struct rt_msghdr is from BSD.
If you are using Linux, use struct msghdr and struct nlmsghdr.
The following example shows header files for them and how to use them.

```
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int raw_socket_test()
{
    /* See https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356 for more details */

    int sock_r;
    struct sockaddr_nl src_sa; /* local (source) socket address */
    struct sockaddr_nl dst_sa;
    int len;
    char buf[4096];
    struct iovec iov = { buf, sizeof(buf) };
    struct msghdr msg = { &dst_sa, sizeof(dst_sa), &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0 }; /* struct rt_msghdr message; in BSD */
    struct nlmsghdr *nlh;

    sock_r = socket(AF_NETLINK,SOCK_RAW,NETLINK_ROUTE); /* sock_r = socket(AF_ROUTE,SOCK_RAW,0); in BSD */
    if(sock_r<0) {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&src_sa, 0, sizeof(src_sa));
    src_sa.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    src_sa.nl_groups = RTMGRP_LINK|RTMGRP_IPV4_ROUTE;
    if (bind(sock_r,(struct sockaddr *)&src_sa,sizeof(src_sa)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        close(sock_r);
        return -1;
    }

    while (1) {
        len = recvmsg(sock_r,&msg,0); /* Unplug Ethernet cable to get a message. */
        if (len < 0 ) {
            perror("recvmsg");
            close(sock_r);
            return -1;
        }

        printf("len : %d\n",len);
        nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)buf;
        printf("nlmsg_type: %d\n",nlh->nlmsg_type);
        if (nlh->nlmsg_type == RTM_DELROUTE) {
            break;
        }
    }

    close(sock_r);

    return 0;
}
```